# Matplotlib - Setting up rcParams for moving xlabel to the top?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need all of my figures to have `xlabel`, `xticks` and `xticklabels` on the top.
Since of that, I wrote a function to adjust `plt.rcParams` which serves for initializing purpose.

However, it seems there is no such parameter to setup `xlabel` to the top in advance. Here is a simplified showcase:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['xtick.bottom'] = False
plt.rcParams['xtick.labelbottom'] = False
plt.rcParams['xtick.top'] = True
plt.rcParams['xtick.labeltop'] = True

data = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))

f,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(data)
ax.set_xlabel('x label')
ax.set_ylabel('y label')
```

Output:
[image]

Currently the way I found to adjust it is putting `ax.xaxis.set_label_position('top')` after calling `ax.set_xlabel('x label')`.

I'm looking for a solution with two goals:

> 1. It change the default x-label position so that every time `ax.set_xlabel()` is called, it shows up at the top.
> 2. This step could be executed before calling `ax.set_xlabel()`

So I don't have to use `ax.xaxis.set_label_position()` individually every time.

Extra:
As @r-beginners mentioned, the [official reference](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick_xlabel_top.html) did provide a example. But in the script they called is `ax.set_title('xlabel top')`, which is different from `ax.set_xlabel('x label')`. Note that a title is always on the top by default, regardless setting up `plt.rcParams` or not. I assume they missed this issue by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the position of the label of the *x* axis is hard-coded.

Let's look at the definition of the `XAxis` class, the relevant file is `.../matplotlib/axis.py`

```
class XAxis(Axis):
    ...
    def _get_label(self):
        # x in axes coords, y in display coords (to be updated at draw
        # time by _update_label_positions)
        label = mtext.Text(x=0.5, y=0,
                           fontproperties=font_manager.FontProperties(
                               size=rcParams['axes.labelsize'],
                               weight=rcParams['axes.labelweight']),
                           color=rcParams['axes.labelcolor'],
                           verticalalignment='top',
                           horizontalalignment='center')

        label.set_transform(mtransforms.blended_transform_factory(
            self.axes.transAxes, mtransforms.IdentityTransform()))

        self._set_artist_props(label)
        self.label_position = 'bottom'
        return label
    ...
```

As you can see, the vertical position of the label is hard-coded in the call to `Text`, `y=0` in display coordinates, to be updated at display time by `_update_label_positions` and the `label_position` is hard-coded to `'bottom'`.

Comment: I see... So there's no way to change default position of xlabel for now :(  Anyway, much appreciate for you bringing up the information about `XAxis`, I've learned something.

Comment: @Pakox.Wang Well, sometimes one has to _accept_ also unpleasant facts… and yes, me too I've learned something new about Matplotlib thanks to your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is an explanation in the [official reference](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick_xlabel_top.html). This will help you deal with it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# plt.rcParams['xtick.bottom'] = plt.rcParams['xtick.labelbottom'] = False
# plt.rcParams['xtick.top'] = plt.rcParams['xtick.labeltop'] = True

x = np.arange(10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x)
ax.set_xlabel('xlabel top')  # Note title moves to make room for ticks

secax = ax.secondary_xaxis('top')
secax.set_xlabel('new label top')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Actually I've tried this and didn't work. Let me check it again later to see if I'm getting anything wrong.

Comment: note that in that example they use `ax.set_title` to set the xlabel, instead of `ax.set_xlabel`. If you set an xlabel as normal, it will still be on the bottom.

Comment: After seeing @tmdavision comment, I ran the official reference code in my environment and it is correctly placed at the top. Have you checked the reference?

Comment: yes I have and my comment still stands. The "xlabel top" you see at the top is set by `ax.set_title()`. If you use `ax.set_xlabel()`, it is still placed at the bottom of the Axes

Comment: right... But that is not a solution to how to get the xlabel on the top of the axes, since a title is different to an xlabel. That is how to put a different text object in that position, which is not what the question asked... Your solution works for the `xticks` and `xticklabels`, but not the `xlabel`

Comment: I finally understand the purpose of your comment. I guess I don't understand it. How would you answer this question? I would be interested in it.

Comment: I edited my question. I'm really sorry for not being explicit enough and cost your time for that.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but I used `ax.secondary_xaxis()` to set the label. Please note that this is not an example of the graph you presented.

Comment: I'm actually looking for a solution with two goals: 1. It change the default x-label position so that every time I call `ax.set_xlabel()`, it shows up at the top. 2. This step can be executed before I call `ax.set_xlabel()`. ...Do you think if I should report this on github, since they use the wrong example and didn't really solve the problem?